# Insert a Georefrenced Image to Autocad

Tags: georeferencing, autocad

I have a satellite image. I want to add this image to Autocad, and keep its original coordinates.
How can I import an image to Autocad 2014 and keep its original coordinates?

Comment: Have you tried the import command? And have you tried Google first, as per the [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour)?

Comment: Yes I tried it and also I tried Raster Image Reference

Comment: Alright, just to play devil's advocate here, are you sure there actually are coordinates in your image file? What format is your image in? Tiff? Jpg? Can't say I know a lot about AutoCAD, but I have created georeferenced images for others to use in there without issues so I'm pretty sure it shouldn't be "that hard" :)

Comment: yes i am sure. It is in .tiff and I also tried .jpg.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use "Autocad map" 
and using the map menu you will find insert image from there you will have your image inserted with its coordinates.

Comment: It probably works in Civil3D as well.